# PyTorch: Higher order derivates of bivariate function

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, mathematical-optimization, autograd

Suppose I have a bivariate function `f(x,y)` with domain `R^d x R^d`, and I have two sets of inputs `X = [x1,x2,...,xm]`  and `Y = [y1,y2,...,yn]`, where each `xi` and `yj` are `d`-dimensional vectors and I would like to compute the matrix with `i,j`th element `[f(xi,yj)]_ij`. I can do this in PyTorch by broadcasting and doing something like `f(X.unsqueeze(1),Y)`.

What I would really like to compute is the following matrix:
`[d/dx d/dy f(xi,yj)]_ij`, where I have assumed each `xi` and `yi` is scalar valued. How would I do this in PyTorch?

I am aware that for single input functions and for first derivatives, I can do something like (using PyTorch's `autograd.grad`):

```
def derivative(x,f):
    return grad(f(x).sum(), x, create_graph=True)[0]
```

Or:

```
def derivative(x, f):
    return grad(f(x), x, grad_outputs=torch.ones(x.shape),create_graph=True)
```

However, I am unable to generalise to the two-dimensional and higher derivative output case! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a sample function and its inputs? btw, you're in need of a jacobian matrix.

Comment: @kmario23 jacobian is first order, OP wants to know about higher order derivatives (e.g. hessian as shown below), at least what I got from: `However, I am unable to generalise to the two-dimensional and higher derivative output case`, if not you're right.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [PyTorch's autograd docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html) you can calculate `hessian` (second order partial-derivatives) of a function and it's inputs similarly to what you did:

```
import torch


def pow_reducer(x):
    return x.pow(3).sum()


inputs = torch.rand(2, 2)
hessian = torch.autograd.functional.hessian(pow_reducer, inputs)
```

Here is the [documentation for Hessian specifically](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.functional.hessian).

Comment: Thanks! Unless I am mistaken, I do not require the Hessian for many reasons: 1) I only require the cross derivates d/dx d/dy f(x,y) at points x_i and y_j. 2) In higher dimensions I would require higher than second-order derivatives, e.g. in two dimension I'd require d/dx_1 d/dx_2 d/dy_1 d/dy_2 f([x_1,x_2],[y_1,y_2]).

Comment: @TimothyHedgeworth You can use multiple `inputs` (variables) for Hessian, I don't think there is another way (someone correct me if I'm wrong). Not sure about higher order derivatives (except chaining `grad` for pointwise `N`th order derivatives).